# Working fine in USB debugging, but built apk not working

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

This specific profile screen of my app alone is not working when I build the apk. When I click on 'Update Profile", the progress indicator is goind on spinning forever. It is working fine in USB debugging though. Any fixes?

Link for reference:
https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/main/lib/widgets/home/bottom-bar/profile_screen.dart

My code:

```
    Future<void> _updateProfile() async {
      final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

      if (user != null) {
        try {
          setState(() {
            isSaving = true;
          });

          // Update profile picture if it's changed
          String? downloadUrl;
          if (profilePic != null) {
            downloadUrl = await _uploadImage(profilePic!);
          }

          // Update other profile information
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .update({
            'name': _nameController.text,
            'week': _weekController.text,
            'bio': _bioController.text,
            if (downloadUrl != null)
              'profilePic': downloadUrl
            else
              'profilePic': profilePic,
          });

          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Profile updated successfully');
        } catch (error) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error updating profile: $error');
        } finally {
          setState(() {
            isSaving = false;
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my code

Comment: Have you checked your app's internet permissions in the Manifest XML files? The debug manifest will have it automatically but not the build one. I haven't checked your manifest file cause I don't have time, just one suggestion.

Comment: I did. I have given it already..